# Как правильно подключить js на определенных страницах wordpress?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, функции

Есть фрагмент с подключением js в задачу которого входит получение переменной tabs со страниц `front-page.php` и `custom-page.php`

```
var tabs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelector("#new-tab .carousel-indicators").children, 0);
```

а для остальных станиц получение этой переменной не нужно, т.к. этого блока на них нет и вызывает ошибку скриптов. Интересует вопрос: как правильно провести проверку и подключить это фрагмент кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариантов вижу несколько:

1. Если это встроенные скрипты, то внесите их прямо в файлы `front-page.php` и `custom-page.php` или сделайте функцию (метод) видимую из `functions.php` и вызывайте в этих файлах;
2. Если это подгружаемые скрипты, то регистрируете в `functions.php` и вызываете в этих файлах через `enqueueScript()`;
3. Как вариант можно держать этот скрипт в общем файле (например в хедере), но проверять на необходимость загрузки через `is_front_page()` и проверку на нужный тип поста;
4. Можно поставить условие в самом JS-коде.

Примерно так:

```
var element, tabs;
element = document.querySelector("#new-tab .carousel-indicators")
if (null !== element) {
    tabs = element.children;
}
```

Еще можно сделать так:

```
var tabs = document.querySelectorAll("#new-tab .carousel-indicators > *")
```

Comment: это не встроенные скрипты, поэтому сработал последний вариант - спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var el = document.querySelector("#new-tab .carousel-indicators");
if (el !== null) {
 tabs = Array.prototype.slice.call(el.children, 0);
 //... и продолжение действий с этой переменной ...
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, он справедлив. Но интересно вот что. Я дал первым ровно такой же ответ и примерно с тем же уровнем комментирования, что и ответ, отмеченный как правильный. Мало того, что ответ проигнорирован, так его еще и заминусовали. Похоже на междусобойчик. Жаль, что Stack Overflow не предоставляет механизмов игнорирования пользователей. Придется самому вести файл с никами пользователей, на чьи вопросы никогда более не собираюсь тратить время.